# Align image and 2 text lines

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align this div so that the image appear first and then the 2 lines after, however i cant seem to make it align proberly.

```css
#overview {
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;


  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  
}

#overview #header-collapse {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ff8217;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 50px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px; 
    text-align: center;
    
    
   
}

#overview #body-list {
    background: #fff;
    height:450px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100%;
    
    border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px; 
     -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px; 
    border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px; 
}

#overview #body-list a {
  text-decoration:none;
}

.list-item:hover {
  background-color: rgba(82, 82, 82, .1);
}
 



.list-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(82, 82, 82, .2);
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;   
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    position: relative;
}


.list-item p {
  margin: 0px;
}
.list-item #header-title {
  color: #954500;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;

}

.list-item #subtitle {
  color: rgb(82, 82, 82);
  opacity: 0.6;
  font-size: 13px;

}

.list-item #list-image {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="overview">
  <div id="header-collapse">
        <h4>
        Oversigt
        </h4>
    </div>
     <div id="body-list">
     <a href="#">
      <div class="list-item">
        <div id="list-image"></div>
          <p id="header-title">Title</p>   
          <p id="subtitle">Subtitle</p>
      </div>
      </a>
     
    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Can you please show me in image or mockup? how you want to align it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest, and most modern way is to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

With this method, the image circle and the text will both be centered vertically, so you don't have to worry about it later.

Place your `header-title` and `subtitle` inside of a div.

```
<div class="list-titles">
  <p id="header-title">Title</p>   
  <p id="subtitle">Subtitle</p>
</div>
```

Then add the following to your `.list-item` class:

```
.list-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

(I also added `margin-right: 10px;` to your image so it looks better xD)

Here is a working [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/yp0ofu5o/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the two titles in a new DIV, then define that new DIV and the DIV of the image as inline-blocks, like this: (you'll have to finetune the margins for distances)

```css
#overview {
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;


  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  
}

#overview #header-collapse {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ff8217;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 50px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px; 
    text-align: center;
    
    
   
}

#overview #body-list {
    background: #fff;
    height:450px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100%;
    
    border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px; 
     -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px; 
    border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px; 
}

#overview #body-list a {
  text-decoration:none;
}

.list-item:hover {
  background-color: rgba(82, 82, 82, .1);
}
 



.list-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(82, 82, 82, .2);
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;   
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    position: relative;
}


.list-item p {
  margin: 0px;
}
.list-item #header-title {
  color: #954500;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;

}

.list-item #subtitle {
  color: rgb(82, 82, 82);
  opacity: 0.6;
  font-size: 13px;

}

.list-item #list-image {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
#list-image, #title-wrapper {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="overview">
  <div id="header-collapse">
        <h4>
        Oversigt
        </h4>
    </div>
     <div id="body-list">
     <a href="#">
      <div class="list-item">
        <div id="list-image"></div>
          <div id="title-wrapper">
            <p id="header-title">Title</p>   
            <p id="subtitle">Subtitle</p>
          </div>
      </div>
      </a>
     
    </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `float:left` to that div.

```
.list-item #list-image {float:left;}
```

Working [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8umq5781/3/)